# Could someone explain steps in this differentian equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this notebook that i copied from a college long time ago with solutions and steps...but i have trouble understanding this particular example if someone could explain to me in plain english what's going on i would be more than grateful.
I copied it in full and it goes like this :

$\ddot y + \frac{2}{x} \dot y + y =0  $

$ y(x)=a(x)*Z(x)$

$\dot y = \dot a(x) \cdot Z(x) + a(x) \cdot \dot Z(x)$

$ \ddot y= \ddot a(x)\cdot Z(x) + \dot a(x) \cdot \dot Z(x)+ \dot a(x) \cdot \dot Z(x)+ a(x) \cdot \ddot Z(x)$

$ 2\dot a+ \frac{2}{x}a=0$

....
$\frac{da}{a} = -\frac{dx}{x}$

$\log_e|a|=- \log_e|x|+C    /\cdot e$

$|a|=\frac 1x \cdot c1 => a= \frac cx= \frac 1x$

$\frac 1x \ddot Z +(\frac 2{x^3}+ \frac 2x \cdot \frac {-1}x+ \frac 1x )\cdot Z=0$

...

I would appreciate if someone could explain the method used here or point to some reference to learn more about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $\ddot y + \frac{2}{x} \dot y + y =0  $

Our foe the ODE.

> $y(x)=a(x)*Z(x)$

Looks for a solution where $y$ consists of two factors.

> $\dot y = \dot a(x) \cdot Z(x) + a(x) \cdot \dot Z(x)$
>
> $ \ddot y= \ddot a(x)\cdot Z(x) + \dot a(x) \cdot \dot Z(x)+ \dot a(x) \cdot \dot Z(x)+ a(x) \cdot \ddot Z(x)$

Taking the derivatives for such an $y$.
Then the ODE is applied and sorted to $Z^{(k)}$:
\begin{align}
0 &= \ddot a(x)\cdot Z(x) + 2\dot a(x) \cdot \dot Z(x)+ a(x) \cdot \ddot Z(x) + \\
& \quad \,\, (2/x) \left(
\dot a(x) \cdot Z(x) + a(x) \cdot \dot Z(x)
\right) +
a(x) \,Z(x) \\
&=
a(x) \cdot \ddot Z(x) +
\left( \ddot a(x) + (2/x) \dot a(x) + a(x) \right) Z(x) +
\left( 2\dot a(x) + (2/x) a(x) \right) \dot Z(x)
\end{align}

> $ 2\dot a+ \frac{2}{x}a=0$

Such an $a$ would make the term with $\dot{Z}$ in the above ODE vanish.

> .... $\frac{da}{a} = -\frac{dx}{x}$
>
> $\log_e|a|=- \log_e|x|+C    /\cdot e$
>
> $|a|=\frac 1x \cdot c1 => a= \frac cx= \frac 1x$

Here [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) is used to solve the ODE for $a$.

> $\frac 1x \ddot Z +(\frac 2{x^3}+ \frac 2x \cdot \frac {-1}x+ \frac 1x )\cdot Z=0$

We still have
$$
a(x) \cdot \ddot Z(x) +
\left( \ddot a(x) + (2/x) \dot a(x) + a(x) \right) Z(x) = 0
$$
to solve, now we insert $a(x) = 1/x$ and get:
$$
(1/x) \cdot \ddot Z(x) +
\left( (2/x^3) + (2/x) (-1/x^2) + (1/x) \right) Z(x) = 0
$$
Note the difference to your version in the middle term.